# JavaScript how to set conditions to make for-loop and .include() filter correctly?

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, for-loop, include

Confused with how to check whether keys in a dictionary matches elements in two or one of the two other arrays then add matched dictionary entries into strings correctly..

The code:

```
target = {
  'A': 1,
  'B': 1,
  'D': 2,
  'L': 2
}

let a_include = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G"];
let b_include = ["H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R"];

a_string = ""
b_string = ""

if (target.length == 0) {
  a_string += "None for a"
  b_string += "None for b"
} else {
  for(const i of Object.keys(target)) {
  const verify = a_include.includes(i)
  const verify2 = b_include.includes(i)
  if (verify && !verify2) {
    a_string += i + ": " + target[i] + "\n";
    b_string += "None for B";
  } else if (!verify && verify2){
    a_string += "None for A"
    b_string += i + ": " + target[i] + "\n"
  } else {
    a_string += "None for A"
    b_string += "None for B"
   }
 }
}
```

Basically the code supposed to check if the dictionary `target`'s keys matches any elements in array `a_include` or `b_include` then add to either `a_string` or `b_string` (With dictionary's key values too)

expected function:

- The code adds `"None for A" or B`  to both `a&b_string`if no entry in `target`.
- If not empty then it runs a for-loop on target's keys and compare it with `a_include` & `b_include`
- If all keys have matches in both arrays,entries include in `a_include` then add to `a_string`, otherwise add to `b_string`
- If all keys matched in `a_include` but none for `b_string` , then add entries to `a_string` but "None for B" for `b_string`, reversibly add "None for A" to `a_string` if no matches to `a_include`.
- If `target` is not empty and no matches for both arrays, then add "None" to both a and b_string

Currently if `target = {'A': 1,'B': 1,'D': 2,'L': 2}`, the output string produces:

```
a_string's output:  "A: 1              b_string's ouput:  "None for BNone for BNone for BL: 2
                     B: 1                                 "
                     D: 2
                     None for A"
```

But what I am trying to output is:

```
a_string's output:  "A: 1              b_string's ouput:  "L: 2"
                     B: 1                                 
                     D: 2"
```

I tried simply remove "None for A/B" to prevent it from wrongly add "None for A/B" into strings, but then the "None for" output won't be produce too if the dictionary has no keys match for one of the arrays:

If `target = {'A': 1,'B': 1,'D': 2}`, the output string produces:

```
a_string's output:  "A: 1              b_string's ouput:  "None for BNone for BNone for B"
                     B: 1                                 
                     D: 2
                     "
```

Instead of:

```
a_string's output:  "A: 1              b_string's ouput:  "None for B"
                     B: 1                                 
                     D: 2
                     "
```

So how to set conditions/loop to make the a and b_string produce the expected output?

**this is actually use for Discord embed so "MessageEmbed field values may not be empty" will occur if remove "None for ..." and leave the strings empty*

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So according to my debugging of your code. The loop goes through every **key** of the **target** dictionary and the conditional statement checks for every **key**. That's where the problem is you don't want the conditional statement to check for unnecessary conditions. For example -

Here,

```
for(const i of Object.keys(target)) {  
  const verify = a_include.includes(i) 
  const verify2 = b_include.includes(i)  
  if (verify && !verify2) { 
    a_string += i + ": " + target[i] + "\n"; 
    b_string += "None for B"; 
  } else if (!verify && verify2){
    a_string += "None for A"
    b_string += i + ": " + target[i] + "\n"
  } else {
    a_string += "None for A"
    b_string += "None for B"
   }
}
```

Suppose , `target = { "A": 1, "B": 1, "D": 2, "L": 2 }`

The loop will check for **A, B, D, and L** and it will confirm the first three,i.e,
**A, B, and D** as **a_string** but it will also check for **L** and assign it to **b_string**.

The problem is for **a_string** the last key,i.e, **L** is a rogue key and thus will assign **"None for A"**, even if the **a_string** has already some text in it, and similarly for **b_string** the first three keys are rouge.

So you get the idea of how your program is working, **now towards the solution** -

```
if (verify && !verify2) { 
    a_string += i + ": " + target[i] + "\n"; 
    b_string += "None for B";  // Remove this line
  } else if (!verify && verify2){
    a_string += "None for A"
    b_string += i + ": " + target[i] + "\n" // Remove this line
  } else {
    a_string += "None for A"
    b_string += "None for B"
  }
```

Instead of checking for the rogue keys there, add a new conditional statement after the loop like this -

```
{...}
    if (verify && !verify2) {
        a_string += i + ": " + target[i] + "\n";
        // b_string += "None for B";
    } else if (!verify && verify2) {
        // a_string += "None for A"
        b_string += i + ": " + target[i] + "\n"
    } else {
        a_string += "None for A"
        b_string += "None for B"
    }
{...}

//after the loop

if (a_string.length === 0) {
    a_string = "None for a";
} 
if (b_string.length === 0) { // edited
    b_string = "None for b"
}
```

This works because after the loop ends the condition checks if either
**a_string** or **b_string** is empty and if it is empty, it will assign the new changes.

> There are more solutions to this particular problem, but I have tried to do it in a simple and understandable way.

Comment: Thanks, but the `else if (b_string.length === 0)` will cause `b_string` to return nothing `""` instead of `"None for b"` if there are no entries for `target` . This was fixed by changing "`else if`" to "`if`" and everything worked after that.

Comment: Thanks a lot I didn't notice it when I was writing the code. Appreciated